# Running multiple headless chrome sessions with docker

Tags: docker, google-chrome-headless

Is it possible to have setup a multiple headless chrome in a docker, since the current version of headless chrome does not support multiple sessions. I need to run tests in a isolations between browser with their own session.

Can someone point me to the right documentations?

Comment: Setup a grid and do it http://tarunlalwani.com/post/deploy-selenium-grid-using-docker-swarm-aws/